# Why is there only one Sorcerer stationed at the New York Sanctum?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

In *Doctor Strange* (2016), Stephen Strange is sent through the portal from the Hong Kong Sanctum to the New York Sanctum when Kaicillius begins his attacks. After wandering around for some time, Strange observes Daniel, another sorcerer, being killed by Kaicillius and his followers, but aside from him, there is no further resistance at the Sanctum (besides Strange). However, we see that at Kamar-Taj at the very least (and later in Hong Kong), there are several dozen if not hundreds of sorcerers following the Sorcerer Supreme. Why were none stationed in New York? If there were so many sorcerers, and the Sanctums were that important, why wouldn't they just station and/or train sorcerers at the sanctums rather than Kamar-Taj?

Comment: I believe the terms of art are "right-sizing" and "off-shoring.". All those people in Kamar-Taj - much cheaper.  I'm sure "just in time" fits in there somewhere too.

Comment: Since they have the sling ring, what’s the real difference between them being in New York or Kamar-Taj?